# need flight simulation library

Tags: c++, simulation

I want to fly an aircraft with a joystick control. 
What i want is some open source flight simulation library that will do the mathematics/physics and produce a position value, i.e., given an initial lat-lon-alt-yaw-pitch-roll it will produce the same. These will then be passed to 3d image generator which will place the aircraft at that location with the same attitude values.

Note that only core/kernel like library is required 3d rendering need not be handled by the library.
Preferably it should be a text based c++ library.

Any suggestions/improvements are welcomed.

Comment: What does it mean for a library to be "text based"?

Comment: Do you mean scriptable library interface instead of pure c/c++ calls to the lib with "text based"?

Comment: What have you researched and found out already?

Comment: by 'text based' what i really meant was that the libratry need not perform the 3d rendering as i have a 3d image generator that will use position and attitude values generated by this library given some initial position and attitude.

Comment: more precisely i need to integrate it with existing cpp application. So, library itself can be in any language as long as i am able to do it

Comment: i would feel oblidged if someone gives the link to more related forum or any other site.

Comment: read the reference manual of 'JSBSim' today and found out that it can take inputs from joystick or other device. Will update further and will try to add more relevant information in future

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you mean with "text based"... but maybe [FlightGear](http://www.flightgear.org/) is an option for your needs. It is open source and can be customized. It is built upon the [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) rendering mechanism and contains physics etc. and is written in C++. Both are open source projects and you are able to modify the code if needed.

If closed source is not an K.O. criteria (you asked for open source) [RTDynamics](http://www.rtdynamics.com/v2/wp/2010/atc/) has some libs that might be interesting.

Comment: This would have been my suggestion for a first look.

Comment: 'FlightGear' uses 'JSBSim', and 'YASim'  library internally for calculations. I need something like 'JSBSim' but not data driven as it is but to be  interactive. I want to maneuver the aircraft.

Comment: What is exacly wrong with JSBSim? I think your question must be more precise and you should give an example.